# asp.net how to access route data from an iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, image-uploading

I have a basic asp.net page with an image upload loaded through an iframe:

```
  <asp:Panel runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="imgCaption" CssClass="imgCaption" PlaceHolder="caption(optional)" />

        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="programmImages" Width="200px" CssClass="offScreen" />

        <asp:Button runat="server" id="hiddenImageUpload" OnClick="UploadImage" CssClass="insButton" Text="Upload" />
   </asp:Panel>
```

the image upload depends on the route data in order to upload but whenever i try to upload the image i get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on this line:

```
var ProgName = Page.RouteData.Values["prog"].ToString();
```

this line works fine in other pages.

so how can i retrieve the route data through the iframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the problem, the iframe is a seperate page than the page it resides in so i had to pass the data as querystrings and it worked fine.